# Python Django Display Nested Objects

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Hi I'm new to django rest framework and I'm trying to serialize 3 nested models. The relationships are:
`hotel_social_media_type` has a one to many relationship to `hotel_social_media`
and `hotel` has one to many relationship to `hotel_social_media`. Right now I can only serialized `hotel` to `hotel_social_media` but I can't serialize `hotel_social_media_type`.

Here's my serializers:

```
class SocialMediaTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes social media type"""

    class Meta:
        model = models.SocialMediaType
        fields = ('name', 'icon', 'url')


class HotelSocialMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes media files"""
    hotel_social_media_type = SocialMediaTypeSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.HotelSocialMedia
        fields = ('url', 'hotel_social_media_type')


class HotelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Serializes Restaurat, Bars, TouristInformation and Tourist Spots """

    hotel_images = HotelImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    hotel_social_media = HotelSocialMediaSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Hotel
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'hotel_images', 'hotel_social_media')
```

Models:

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    """Database model for hotels"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the model as a string"""
        return self.name

class HotelImage(models.Model):
    """Image upload for hotel"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='hotel_images', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the model as a string"""
        return self.name

class SocialMediaType(models.Model):
    """Social Media Type eg: fb, twitter"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the model as a string"""
        return self.name

class HotelSocialMedia(models.Model):
    """Social Media"""

    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, related_name='hotel_social_media', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(SocialMediaType, related_name='hotel_social_media_type', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return the model as a string"""
        return self.name
```

Current result is:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alta Vista",
  "hotel_images": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Alta Vista",
      "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/hotel-1.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "hotel_social_media": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/abscbnNEWS"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Alta Vista",
  "hotel_images": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Alta Vista",
      "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/hotel-1.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "hotel_social_media": [
    {
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/abscbnNEWS",
      "hotel_social_media_type": {
        "name": "Facebook",
        "icon": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/fb-1.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}



`hotel_social_media` must also display `hotel_social_media_type`
```

Comment: Could you show your models?

Comment: @kamilyrb I updated my post. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your model, you must use `type` keyword instead of `hotel_social_media_type` in your `HotelSocialMediaSerializer`. Because your `HotelSocialMedia` has `type` field for relation with `HotelSocialMediaType`.To change keyword can solve your problem.

```
class HotelSocialMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   """Serializes media files"""
    type = SocialMediaTypeSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.HotelSocialMedia
        fields = ('url', 'type')
```

If you want to use `hotel_social_media_typ`e keyword, you can use `SerializerMethodField` like that:

```
class HotelSocialMediaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   """Serializes media files"""
    hotel_social_media_type = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = models.HotelSocialMedia
        fields = ('url', 'hotel_social_media_type')

    def get_hotel_social_media_type(self.obj):
        serializer = SocialMediaTypeSerializer(obj.type)
        return serializer.data
```